# Regex look for all quotes not preceded by a comma

Tags: regex

I have a CSV file that is not well formatted and I need to look for extra quotes.

This is what it looks like:

```
"1","title","desc desc dejdg sdjgh djhg"

"2","title2","desc jhgdj "jhsgfjhsgd" jhgd"
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I need to look for any `"` that doesn't have a `,` before:

```
(\")(?!\,)
```

This would mean look for any `"` that doesn't have a `,` right after,  but I don't know how to look for a `,` *before* the `"`.

Comment: What language/flavor are you using ? You'll need a lookbehind which isn't supported in all flavors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you are asking for would be

```
(?<!,)"
```

Alternatively, if you're not averse to matching more than you need you can use

```
(^|[^,])"
```

which would match the preceding non-comma as well as the double-quote, but support for it should be more widespread (excluding `findstr`).

However, for parsing CSV files you should use a proper parser as any regex-based solution (at least those I have seen so far for this task) is

- error-prone
- unreadable
- slow

Comment: This A will fail the moment when it's clear that the OP is using JS :)

Comment: That will make my second statement even more true, then ;)

Comment: worked, combined with other operators of course. I'm really bad at matching things that come before a given something in certain conditions. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
[^,](\")
```

?

Notice that this doesn't detect quotes at the beginning of the line (which, technically, *are* quotes not preceded by commas), but for your usage this is fine, since quotes at the beginning of the line aren't an error in a CSV file.

Comment: This won't match a quote at the beginning of a line.

Comment: @Joey: which is good, since a quote at the beginning of the line is perfectly fine in a CSV file.

Comment: Thanks! Soon enough I'll have something of a database of regex examples

Comment: Matteo: The point is that a quote at the beginning of the line is *also* a quote that isn't preceded by a comma.

Comment: @Joey: I know and I noticed soon after posting, but since he's explained what he's going to use this regex for, I didn't "correct" it, since the correction would make the regex mark as "incorrect quotes" even quotes that are correct (in particular, quotes at the beginning of the line). Check the example in the question text: the quotes at the beginning of the line aren't to be marked as error, only quotes in the middle of the line that aren't preceded by a comma.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET, you might use the [TextFieldParser Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser.aspx). Add the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` reference to your project and try this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var tfp = new TextFieldParser("input.txt"))
        {
            tfp.Delimiters = new string[] { "," };
            tfp.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = false;
            while (!tfp.EndOfData)
            {
                var fields = tfp.ReadFields();
                fields.ToList().ForEach(field =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(field);
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good point, missed that. I'm going to delete the answer if doesn't apply.